# ASP.NET - show / hide jquery .ready code programmatically

Tags: jquery, .net, tablednd

I have aspnet form, were jquery function is load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = document.getElementById('<%=grdNews.ClientID%>');
        var tableDnD = new TableDnD();
        tableDnD.init(table);
    })
</script>
```

*FYI: this is not my code and I haven't developed TableDnD class. This clss attaches drag & drop functionality for one table in aspnet form.*

Everything works fine here.

However, now I have a new requirement: for some users **I do not need** to do this jquery, for some - this jquery is **still necessary**. How can I achieve this programmatically? This would be something like:

```
ON PAGE LOAD:
if (User == SpecificUser) 
{
     ALLOW_ABOVE_JQUERY (LOAD JQUERY FUNCTION ON LOAD) //?HOW
}
else 
{
     DO_NOT_ALLOW_ABOVE_JQUERY (DISABLE LOADING JQUERY FUNCTION ON LOAD) //?HOW
}
```

It is something about javascript in code behind, but this is $(document).ready that makes me confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use server tags in the markup:

```
<% if (User == SpecificUser) { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var table = document.getElementById('<%=grdNews.ClientID%>');
    var tableDnD = new TableDnD();
    tableDnD.init(table);
  });
</script>
<% } %>
```

Alternatively you can put it in a place holder:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ScriptContainer" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var table = document.getElementById('<%=grdNews.ClientID%>');
    var tableDnD = new TableDnD();
    tableDnD.init(table);
  });
</script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then hide the content from code behind:

```
if (User != SpecificUser) {
  ScriptContainer.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I like PlaceHolder solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a javascript variable `shouldDnD` and add the necessary code to set its value on the server and use that variable later to decide whether to turn on DnD.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var shouldDnD = <%= User == SpecificUser %>
if (shouldDnD) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = document.getElementById('<%=grdNews.ClientID%>');
        var tableDnD = new TableDnD();
        tableDnD.init(table);
    })
}
</script>
```

You may have the shouldDnD check inside the function as well, depending on what the rest of your code looks like.